Imprimir imagen en hoja desde una tabla
quiero imprimir una tabla en una hoja, lo cual ya logre, pero ahora me pidieron que tenga un logo en la parte superior, lo cual creí sería solo poner la imagen pero al momento de mandar a la impresora desaparece la imagen. Quisiera saber como podría hacerle para que me la muestre, el código es el siguiente.


function printDiv(nombreDiv) {
  var contenido = document.getElementById(nombreDiv).innerHTML;
  var contenidoOriginal = document.body.innerHTML;

  document.body.innerHTML = contenido;
  window.print();
  document.body.innerHTML = contenidoOriginal;

}
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" title="Imprimir" onclick="printDiv('tablaImp')" style="text-decoration: none;"><i
            class="fa-solid fa-print"></i><span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Imprimir</span></a>

<div id="tablaImp">
  <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4" style="text-align: center;"><img style="width: 40%;" src="https://logodownload.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/stack-overflow-logo-0.png" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4" style="text-align: center;">SALIDA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <?php
                    echo '<b>Referencia: </b>', $referencia['Referencia'];
                    ?>
      </td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <?php
                    echo '<b>No. Pedido: </b>', $noPed;
                    ?>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><b>Fecha de impresión: </b></td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <?php echo $fecha; ?>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <th>Marca</th>
      <th>Producto</th>
      <th>No. Cajas</th>
      <th>Cantidad</th>
    </tr>

    <?php
            foreach ($datos as $dato) {
                ?>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <?php echo $dato['Marca']; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
          <?php echo $dato['Producto']; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
          <?php echo $dato['Contador']; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
          <?php echo $dato['Cantidad']; ?>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <?php
            }
            ?>
  </table>
</div>



Espero puedan ayudarme de antemano gracias.

No se aprecia el problema que describes en el código que has agregado
